# wxPython panel color does not match with frame background

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, wxpython, panel

While using wxPython in creating GUI for Windows, I am encountering a problem where the wx.Panel's background colour and parent frame's background colours are not matching (one is light gray while the other one is of darker hue). However, this is not evident in Linux with the same code.
How can I match the two different background colours in Windows?
The embedded screenshot may give a fair idea of what I am talking about.
!Screenshot of the GUI[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3F0z.jpg)

Comment: what is the parent of "select" label? of others light gray objects ?

Comment: @kraymer The three light coloured boxes are separate wx.Panels with widgets laid out using BoxSizer. Parent to all these widgets are a default wx.Frame window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a container panel that has the `wx.Frame` as parent (hence you get the light gray background color for the frame).
Use this panel as parent for all widgets contained in the frame.

Edit: the only reason is that default background color for frames is dark grey on Windows, see [WxFAQ](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxFAQ#Why_are_backgrounds_of_windows_ugly.2C_dark_grey_on_Windows.3F_I_want_them_like_my_dialog_boxes.).

Comment: I would positively consider this as a solution to the problem, but from an academic point of view it would be interesting to find out the reason for such behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
panel = wx.Panel(frame)
panel.SetBackgroundColour(frame.GetBackgroundColour())
```